# spoilers in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spoilers

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/how-come-river-song-knew-about-the-events-of-demons-run-before-they-happened) I want to reply to the second part of the answer which is spoilered (as I spoilered my question). But the spoiler markdown doesn't work in comments (>!).

Would it be possible to allow spoilers in comments?

Comment: Can you not just obliquely refer to the material in the comment?

Answer (score 4):

Comments are intentionally second-class citizens and lightweight in terms of implementation requirements and user experience impact. I don't think adding another feature to them will be well-received. If “spoiler” comments existed at all, the whole comment would probably be a spoiler, and even then I don't think the feature has much chance of being accepted.

I don't like it much myself. Comments are already displayed in a low-key way; I don't think you'll be reading them by accident. I'd be quite comfortable with a “comments are always spoily” policy, especially on answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could [rot-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot_13) the spoiler:

> Lbqn vf Yhxr'f sngure!

If you're feeling friendly, you could even link to a [decoder](http://rot13.de/index.php)/encoder.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to include a spoiler in a comment, and you are not commenting on a post that implicitly spoils the respective plot-element, just prefix it with a written spoiler warning indicating **what** exactly will be spoiled by the comment.

Example:

> *[**WARNING**: Integral plot details of "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back" will be spoiled by reading this.]* The argument in your answer is wrong, because when Luke meets Vader in Cloud City it is disclosed that Vader is actually Luke's father. So, he couldn't possibly have been a time travelling robot from the future.